# Why do Harry and Hermione arrive at Buckbeak's execution time after using the time Turner?

Tags: harry-potter

In Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Hermione turns the time Turner 3 times to take herself and Harry 3 hours back in the past.  When they do so its 11:55 so that means they go back to 8:55. This takes them to the time when Buckbeak is about to be executed.  But the execution is supposed to happen at sunset (which I  assume can't be later than 7). So how are they there at 7 when they only went back 3 hours from 11:55?

From the chapter 16, "Professor Trelawney's Prediction":

> "It's from Hagrid', said Harry, ripping the note open. "Buckbeak's appea - it's set for the sixth."
>
> "That;s the day we finish our exams," said Hermoine, still looking everywhere for her Arithmancy book.

Also from the same chapter just after Trelawney makes her prediction:

> "Buckbeak lost", said Ron weakly. "Hagrid's just sent this."
>
> Hagrid's note was dry this tim, no tears had splattered it, yet his hand seemed to have shaken so much as he wrote that it was hardly legible
>
> > *Lost appeal. They're going to execute at **sunset**. Nothing you can do. Don't come down. I don't want you to see it.*
> >
> > *Hagrid*

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/192646/100430

Comment: @R_D  It is a well known fact that the length of the day, and thus the times of sunrise and sunset, varies over the course of a year in a single location.  And places in higher latitudes have greater variation in the times of sunrise and sunset than places in lower latitudes.  You may assume that sunset must be before 7 PM, but there are places where in some seasons sunset is always after 7 PM.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sunset can be much later than 7:00 pm.

I don't remember when this scene takes place, but I think it was at the end of the book, so I picked the data May 15 1994. We don't know where Hogwarts is. A line from a movie said that it's not far from Dufftown.

I looked up the [sunset time for this time and place](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=What%20time%20was%20sunset%20in%20Dufftown%20%20Scotland%20on%20May%2015%201994) and found that it happened at 9:26 pm. The real sunset time varies a lot depending on time and location. What I like about this is that it gives us another clue for the location of Hogwarts, and I'd love to see a fan take this into account.

Comment: Life threatening adventures are always at the end of the school year.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know sunset could be that late! And yes this adventure happens after their last exam

Comment: @RalfFriedl, I hope you get a ton of upvotes for that comment.

Comment: @R_D, Since you've read this carefully, could you shed more light on when the sunset happened in this scene? Did they go back to exactly 8:55? Does the book indicate whether this is immediately before sunset, or does a lot of stuff happen before then?

Comment: The date this occurs is on the 6th of June. The book says this is a Thursday, but actually the Thursday was 9th June. They go back exactly 3 hours from shortly after 11:55pm; i.e. to around 8:56pm. They spend 5 or so minutes in a cupboard, then sprint to the forest near Hagrid's, via the greenhouses. They lurk around for 5-10 minutes as their past selves visit Hagrid, then maybe 5 minutes as they read and sign the execution notice. Sunset should thus be no later than 9:30pm. This puts Hogwarts too far south (below Birmingham); or else they had to sprint for over 40 minutes to get to Hagrid's.

Comment: @Showsni, I'd recommend that your write that up as an answer -- that it's implausible in the opposite direction. I bet there are ways to make it work. Maybe our heroes were delayed a little longer, maybe there are mountains to the west, and maybe wizard time zones are a little different, maybe they don't use Summer Time.

Comment: @RalfFriedl Voldemort is very considerate; Harry should get a proper education.