# Isn't Juliet Butler an expert in 8 martial arts?

Tags: artemis-fowl, artemis-fowl-the-eternity-code

In the chapter 'Running in the Family', the following lines are written :-

> By the time she was eight, Juliet was a third Dan black belt in seven disciplines. By eleven, she was beyond belts.

In the same chapter :-

> These lessons included *Cos Ta'pa*, a martial art developed by Madame Ko herself,...

Taking these lines as fact, we proceed to 'Ghosts in the Machine', where the following line is written :-

> Juliet had been trained in seven martial arts disciplines.

The first line makes it crystal clear that Juliet already knew seven martial arts disciplines by the age of eleven. Also, she had already been going to Madame Ko's classes since she was around the age of ten, where she undoubtedly had a lot of time to learn *Cos Ta'pa*, which is, like mentioned above also a martial art. And the last time I checked, seven plus one equals eight.

Is this an error? Or does this indicate that she had not yet started learning it?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. This is a perfectly framed question. Anyone care to explain?

Comment: Cos Ta'pa is one of the seven disciplines she mastered. Why do you think there's an error?

Comment: @fez It seems pretty clear in the chapter that the Cos Ta'pa came several years after the seven disciplines.

Comment: @InfinityMilestone Some people don't like certain types of questions. Consider, for example, [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/191139/how-long-did-harrys-belief-that-he-would-live-with-sirius-last) similar type of question which has 10 downvotes.

Comment: @fez, the book makes it clear that Juliet was a master of 7 disciplines by the age of eleven, and that Juliet joined the Academy somewhere at the age of 10, and that she must have ample time to learn Cos Ta'pa from Madame Ko.

Comment: Maybe that should be added to the question? Without reading the chapter for more clarification the way it's written is a tad ambiguous

Comment: @fez, your wish is my command. :)

Comment: Does Cos Ta'pa definitely count as a discipline?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, yes. I just checked

Comment: @InfinityMilestone: with the Artemis Fowl Martial Art Discipline Recognition Adjudication Board?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, you know it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Juliet had been trained in seven martial arts disciplines, one of which was *Cos Ta'pa.***

Butler himself took charge of Juliet's training when she was four years old and he taught her "various forms of martial arts":

> Juliet's training began at age four. After kindergarten each day, Domovoi Butler would escort his little sister to the Fowl Estate dojo, where he instructed her in the various forms of martial arts.
>
> <sub>*Artemis Fowl and the Eternity Code* - Chapter 4: "Running in the Family"</sub>

Butler (being Butler) would have trained Juliet in every martial art he could, including the martial art *specifically designed for bodyguards by Butler's old sensei*. There is no way he would have neglected to include such an important part of Juliet's training.

The passage:

> Lessons included *Cos Ta'pa*, a martial art developed by Madame Ko herself [...]

doesn't necessarily mean that Juliet (or any of the other acolytes) aren't already trained in *Cos Ta'pa*, just that it was included in the lessons.

Butler males enroll in Madame Ko's Personal Protection Academy at age 10, and spend 6 months training to be a bodyguard, and the other 6 months guarding a low-risk principal. Juliet

> [...] decided she would combine both roles, spending half the year with Angeline Fowl, and the other half **honing her martial arts skills** in Madame Ko's camp.
>
> <sub>*Artemis Fowl and the Eternity Code* - Chapter 4: "Running in the Family"</sub>

Note it says she was "honing" her martial arts skills with Madame Ko, implying she had prior skills that she was just making better and better.

The lessons at Madame Ko's Academy also included "advanced weaponry" (among others), which to me means the acolytes would all have some base knowledge around weapons to begin with, and the lessons are honing or perfecting those skills.

So by age 11 Juliet would have had been "honing her martial arts skills" with Madame Ko for 6 months and, Madame Ko being Madame Ko, even after only 6 months she would be "beyond belts" in the martial arts she had been instructed in, which included *Cos Ta'pa*.